# ASP Dynamic way to verify all Textboxes are not null

Tags: asp.net

What i'm trying to do is basically create one way to verify that all textboxes are full.  So if i Have 11 textboxes on one page I can basically run this QC check and verify each textbox ha some information.

this is what I'm trying to do but it's not working out.

```
private void VerifyTextBoxes()
{
    Control[] AllTextBoxes = FindControl("TextBox");
    foreach(Control c in AllTextBoxes)
    {
        //verify work here
    }
}
```

The problem is two fold, I know that FindControl is not converted into an [], but i'm not sure how to do that.  Also, the FindControl is looking for an ID name, is there a way to find it by type?  For example all TextBoxes?  Or all ComboBoxes?

Here is my aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdministrationContent" runat="Server">
<ul>
    <li>
        <asp:Label ID="DealerShipID" runat="server" Text="Dealership ID"></asp:Label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="InputDealershipID" runat="server" Width="250px">
        </telerik:RadTextBox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you are adding your textboxes dynamically, why don't you add a RequiredValidator for each one of them either?

Comment: @Bazzz i'm not adding them dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through all controls and pull out only the TextBoxes:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<RadTextBox> allTextBoxes = new List<RadTextBox>();
    FindTextBoxes(this, allTextBoxes);

    foreach (RadTextBox tb in allTextBoxes)
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}

private void FindTextBoxes(Control parent, List<RadTextBox> allTextBoxes)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        RadTextBox tb = c as RadTextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            allTextBoxes.Add(tb);
        }

        FindTextBoxes(c, allTextBoxes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Drumboog what exactly am i passing into FindtaxtBoxes(parent); what is the parent coming from

Comment: you would initially pass in the Page itself.  This will handle recursion so that all `TextBoxe`s throughout the page will be identified... even if they are nested within other controls.  I've updated my response to be a little more explicit if you were calling it from say the Page_Load.

Comment: drumboog - my edit is up top, sorry i'm such a noob, so let me ask the dumb question how do you pass the page?

Comment: Where do you want to perform the validation?  On the click event of a Button?  If so, then in the event handler of that button you would just put `FindTextBoxes(this.Page)`.

Comment: That's weird... it seems to work ok in my simple test with a couple of TextBoxes and Panels.  I assume you're trying to pull out the RadTextBox controls?  Did you change the references in my code from TextBox to RadTextBox?

Comment: druum yep i made sure to change that to that type, could this have something to do with this is a child master page of a parent master page

Comment: Yes... in that case, instead of passing in `this.Page`, try `this.Master`.

Comment: drumboog using this.master only finds one control

Comment: I guess that makes sense too if you running this code in the child master page... you probably need to pass in just `this`... that way, it will use the child master page instead of its master page (the parent).

Comment: drumboog - what i think the 1 control refers to is the 1 control on of this child master pages contentholder, but how do i find whats in that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14247/discussion-between-mike-and-drumboog)

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool VerifyTextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    var myTextBoxs = parent.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

    bool allgood=true;

    foreach(TextBox txtbx in myTextBoxs)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbx.Text.ToString())
        allgood=false;
    }
    return allgood;
}
```

Use this line where you want to verify

```
if(!VerifyTextBoxes(Content1))
{
    //Do something is not verfied, i.e found null
}
```

Comment: Ashwin, i'm not exactly sure what textboxsholder represents, I please see my edit

Comment: Interestingly enough is does not know what Content1 is

Comment: You tried and it gave an error did it? Try the modified code.

Comment: Ashwin, I tried the above code, and I passed in (this.Page) however it comes back with no results, could this be an issue because this is a child master page of a parent master page?

Comment: It should return either true or false, what is it returning?

Comment: Ashwin - it cannot find any Controls of that type